# Rselenium scraping specific var from <script>

Tags: r, rselenium

Using Rselenium with firefox to do a personal webscraping project. This is a screen shot from the HTML inspector:
[image]

I need to extract the information in data: [46, 59, 41, 25, 66, 2, 97, 9, ]
Can't do it with the usual xpath, any ideas on what I can do?
I just require these nine numbers which will be stored.

EDIT:
I've used the following code to get this output:
textprog<-remDr$findElement(using="xpath","/html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIV6Z.png)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIV6Z.png)/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/script")$getElementAttribute('outerHTML')[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIV6Z.png)]
doc<-htmlParse(textprog)
[image]

I now just need to extract the value contained in "data:[ ... ]" into a list.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider an approach as below. It would be easier to help you if you could provide the web link to the website.

```
library(RSelenium)
library(stringr)

url <- "www.my_url.com"
shell('docker run -d -p 4446:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4446L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)

html_Text <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
script <- stringr::str_extract_all(html_Text, pattern = "<script>[^>]*</script>")
data <- stringr::str_extract_all(script, pattern = "data: \\[(\\d{1,3}\\,|)(\\d{1,3}\\,|)(\\d{1,3}\\,|)(\\d{1,3}\\,|)(\\d{1,3}\\,|)(\\d{1,3}\\,|)(\\d{1,3}\\,|)(\\d{1,3}\\,|)(\\d{1,3}\\,|)\\]")
```

Comment: Hi there, unfortunately you would need to login to access it. It’s for a sports manager game where I’m scraping information on prospects to be drafted. So this is imbedded within a loop over 200 other prospects. I figured the would be enough information since I just need the code to be able to extract what is contained within that <script> section and then need to extract the data component of it that holds the specific values im after

Comment: Good! I glad it is useful for you.

Comment: I'm getting the following error on the script line: 

Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.11 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required

Comment: Further, this method won't work as there are numerous "script" tags in the html of the page. Is there any way I can isolate the extraction from the id="dev-progress" tag at the top of the screenshot?

Comment: I've added an edit for where I'm up to!